# RISC-V register gets replaced during system call

Tags: c++, inline-assembly, riscv

The floating-point return value of an inline assembly system call gets unexpectedly saved by the compiler and then restored after the call.

```
inline float fsyscallf(long n, float farg0)
{
    register long   a0 asm("a0");
    register float fa0 asm("fa0") = farg0;
    register long syscall_id asm("a7") = n;

    asm volatile ("scall"
        : "=r"(a0), "+r"(fa0) : "r"(syscall_id));

    return fa0;
}
```

The system call that returns a floating-point value from FA0.

```
syscall.hpp:149
   101fc:       e00507d3                fmv.x.w a5,fa0
   10200:       00000073                ecall
   10204:       f0078553                fmv.w.x fa0,a5
```

The compiler saves and restores FA0 during the system call. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using `register asm` variables in the first place?  The whole point of the extended asm syntax is to tell the compiler how you want the registers loaded for the asm block, and outside the block, why do you care where the variables are?

Comment: @NateEldredge When you need specific registers that you can't get with just the constraints (which is the case here), local register variables are the documented way to do it.

Comment: @gonzo Why do you have `a0` listed as an output and not as a clobber?

Comment: @gonzo And what about using `+f` as the constraint instead of `+r`?

Comment: You magnificent man. I tried your previous ideas, but changing the +r to +f made it work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint `r` means a general-purpose register, but you need `fa0`, which is a floating-point register, so use `f` as the constraint instead. Change `"+r"` to `"+f"`.